# Displaying Blob Value from JTable cell to JLabel

Tags: java, image, swing, jtable, listselectionlistener

I have a ListSelectionListener that gets Blob value from a certain row cell 
and loads it to a JLabel. The issue here is that everytime i clicked on a row, it loads the image to the JLabel before highlighting the row. And there is a delay when loading the image. How can i resolve this issue?

```
      mytable.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener(){

        @Override
        public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {                                                                                              

               BufferedImage buffImg = null;
               ImageIcon imgIcon = null;
               Blob blob = (Blob) tableItem.getValueAt(selectedRow, 0);
               InputStream is = blob.getBinaryStream();                                               
               buffImg = ImageIO.read(is);                                                  
               imgIcon = new ImageIcon(buffImg.getScaledInstance(label.getWidth(), label.getHeight(),
                     Image.SCALE_SMOOTH));                                                  


                 label.setIcon(imgIcon);
         }

    });
```

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example). 2) A single blank line of white space in source code is all that is *ever* needed.  Blank lines after `{` or before `}` are also typically redundant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve the problem, query [`ListSelectionEvent.getValueIsAdjusting()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/event/ListSelectionEvent.html#getValueIsAdjusting--) & only progress if it is `false`.  If one row is selected and the user clicks a different row, there will be two events fired.  One for the deselection of the first row, the 2nd for the selection of the alternate row.

---

As an aside.  I would strongly recommend storing the `Image` in the table as opposed to a `Blob` - so there is no potentially long running code on table row selection.

Comment: Great! it works. Previously, I tried to store the Image in the JTable cell, but due to the long loading time i switched to this alternative instead. Because my JTable is binded to a Search Textfield with a documentListener.

Comment: Is there an equivalent of ListSelectionEvent.getValueIsAdjusting() method for DocumentEvent? because my JTextField is retrieving data from database on every keystroke and is lagging.

Comment: You might start the DB query after a single shot Swing `Timer` fires (delay the start for 250-500 msec).  On each document event, restart the single instance of the timer.  Of course then run the DB access using a `SwingWorker` so as not to block the Event Dispatch Thread of the GUI.  See [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for further details.